# Jquery, i have a div it is clickable except when i put it in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, click, nested

I can't get my jquery to work in wordpress even when if it is on a normal .htm page it works fine.

i'm trying to click something and fire of an alert

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#blue").click(function() {
       alert("Hello world!");
     });
   });
```

this normally works in an .htm file, but when i stick it in the header file of my wordpress page, nothing happens when i click on the div.

```
<div id="blue" style="display:table-cell;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

By the way the div looks like this on my wordpress page

```
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute;top:0px;height:50px;width:100%;background-color:black;text-align:center;">
<div id="menuTable" style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
<div id="a1" class="start" >Andie</div>
<div id="a2" class="start" >Work</div>
<div id="a3" class="start" >Play</div>
<div id="a4" class="start" >Dream</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the page? this needs to be seen in context

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the div with id=blue on your wordpress page.

I see a div with id=menu  that looks the similar.  Make sure your JavaScript references the new ID.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu").click(function() {
       alert("Hello world!");
     });
   });
```

Comment: something is up because jquery will hardly work in wordpress but works fine on an .htm file the id="blue" div is the box above the main code box

Comment: @andie...you need to revise your question then...because you say "by the way the div looks like this on the wordpress page.  Your javascript references blue.  but on your wordpress page it references menu or at least the div is similar to menu.  I simply assumed that your javascript was in accurate.  On top of that you say it doesn't work.  Do you get a scripting error? Have your debugged using firebug or IE8 development tools?

Comment: right debugging, thanks for that, It's solved now no debugging errors, thank you John

Answer (score 0):

fixed.. i had to add the jquery google file from google? y'know the one that makes the jquery work.. i thought wordpress had an ........   ahhhh... inhouse one but it did not work at all